# Trixbox hangs up when I call

Tags: trixbox

When I call to a number, trixbox hungs up when the person I call unhangs. The logs says:

```
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [1403@from-internal:1] Macro("SIP/100-00000008", "user-callerid,SKIPTTL,") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:1] Set("SIP/100-00000008", "AMPUSER=100") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:2] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "0?report") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:3] ExecIf("SIP/100-00000008", "1?Set(REALCALLERIDNUM=100)") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:4] Set("SIP/100-00000008", "AMPUSER=100") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:5] Set("SIP/100-00000008", "AMPUSERCIDNAME=Leandro") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:6] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "0?report") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:7] Set("SIP/100-00000008", "AMPUSERCID=100") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:8] Set("SIP/100-00000008", "CALLERID(all)="Leandro" <100>") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:9] ExecIf("SIP/100-00000008", "1?Set(CHANNEL(language)=es)") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:10] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "1?continue") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Goto (macro-user-callerid,s,19)
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:19] NoOp("SIP/100-00000008", "Using CallerID "Leandro" <100>") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [1403@from-internal:2] Set("SIP/100-00000008", "_NODEST=") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [1403@from-internal:3] Macro("SIP/100-00000008", "record-enable,100,OUT,") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-record-enable:1] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "1?check") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Goto (macro-record-enable,s,4)
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-record-enable:4] AGI("SIP/100-00000008", "recordingcheck,20110624-142634,1308918394.15") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Launched AGI Script /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/recordingcheck
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:  recordingcheck,20110624-142634,1308918394.15: Outbound recording not enabled
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- <SIP/100-00000008>AGI Script recordingcheck completed, returning 0
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-record-enable:5] MacroExit("SIP/100-00000008", "") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [1403@from-internal:4] Macro("SIP/100-00000008", "dialout-trunk,1,1403,,") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:1] Set("SIP/100-00000008", "DIAL_TRUNK=1") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:2] GosubIf("SIP/100-00000008", "0?sub-pincheck,s,1") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:3] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "0?disabletrunk,1") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:4] Set("SIP/100-00000008", "DIAL_NUMBER=1403") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:5] Set("SIP/100-00000008", "DIAL_TRUNK_OPTIONS=tr") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:6] Set("SIP/100-00000008", "OUTBOUND_GROUP=OUT_1") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:7] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "1?nomax") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Goto (macro-dialout-trunk,s,9)
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:9] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "0?skipoutcid") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:10] Set("SIP/100-00000008", "DIAL_TRUNK_OPTIONS=") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:11] Macro("SIP/100-00000008", "outbound-callerid,1") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-outbound-callerid:1] ExecIf("SIP/100-00000008", "0?Set(CALLERPRES()=)") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-outbound-callerid:2] ExecIf("SIP/100-00000008", "0?Set(REALCALLERIDNUM=100)") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-outbound-callerid:3] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "1?normcid") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Goto (macro-outbound-callerid,s,6)
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-outbound-callerid:6] Set("SIP/100-00000008", "USEROUTCID=") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-outbound-callerid:7] Set("SIP/100-00000008", "EMERGENCYCID=") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-outbound-callerid:8] Set("SIP/100-00000008", "TRUNKOUTCID=") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-outbound-callerid:9] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "1?trunkcid") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Goto (macro-outbound-callerid,s,12)
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-outbound-callerid:12] ExecIf("SIP/100-00000008", "0?Set(CALLERID(all)=)") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-outbound-callerid:13] ExecIf("SIP/100-00000008", "0?Set(CALLERID(all)=)") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-outbound-callerid:14] ExecIf("SIP/100-00000008", "0?Set(CALLERPRES()=prohib_passed_screen)") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:12] ExecIf("SIP/100-00000008", "1?AGI(fixlocalprefix)") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Launched AGI Script /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/fixlocalprefix
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:   == fixlocalprefix: Dialpattern 1. matched. 1403 -> 1403
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- <SIP/100-00000008>AGI Script fixlocalprefix completed, returning 0
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:13] Set("SIP/100-00000008", "OUTNUM=1403") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:14] Set("SIP/100-00000008", "custom=DAHDI/g0") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:15] ExecIf("SIP/100-00000008", "0?Set(DIAL_TRUNK_OPTIONS=M(setmusic^))") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:16] Macro("SIP/100-00000008", "dialout-trunk-predial-hook,") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk-predial-hook:1] MacroExit("SIP/100-00000008", "") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:17] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "0?bypass,1") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:18] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "0?customtrunk") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:19] Dial("SIP/100-00000008", "DAHDI/g0/1403,300,") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:34] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Called g0/1403
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- DAHDI/1-1 answered SIP/100-00000008
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [h@macro-dialout-trunk:1] Macro("SIP/100-00000008", "hangupcall,") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-hangupcall:1] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "1?skiprg") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Goto (macro-hangupcall,s,4)
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-hangupcall:4] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "1?skipblkvm") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Goto (macro-hangupcall,s,7)
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-hangupcall:7] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "1?theend") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Goto (macro-hangupcall,s,9)
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-hangupcall:9] Hangup("SIP/100-00000008", "") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:   == Spawn extension (macro-hangupcall, s, 9) exited non-zero on 'SIP/100-00000008' in macro 'hangupcall'
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:   == Spawn extension (macro-dialout-trunk, h, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/100-00000008'
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Hungup 'DAHDI/1-1'
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:   == Spawn extension (macro-dialout-trunk, s, 19) exited non-zero on 'SIP/100-00000008' in macro 'dialout-trunk'
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:   == Spawn extension (from-internal, 1403, 4) exited non-zero on 'SIP/100-00000008'
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [h@from-internal:1] Macro("SIP/100-00000008", "hangupcall") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-hangupcall:1] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "1?skiprg") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Goto (macro-hangupcall,s,4)
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-hangupcall:4] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "1?skipblkvm") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Goto (macro-hangupcall,s,7)
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-hangupcall:7] GotoIf("SIP/100-00000008", "1?theend") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Goto (macro-hangupcall,s,9)
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-hangupcall:9] Hangup("SIP/100-00000008", "") in new stack
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:   == Spawn extension (macro-hangupcall, s, 9) exited non-zero on 'SIP/100-00000008' in macro 'hangupcall'
[Jun 24 14:26:36] VERBOSE[3333] logger.c:   == Spawn extension (from-internal, h, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/100-00000008'
[Jun 24 14:26:36] DEBUG[2866] pbx.c: FONALITY: This thread has already held the conlock, skip locking
```

what's happening? thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's dialing "1403" on the land line.  I'm guessing you're in southern Alberta as that's where the area code belongs but it's not going to work to dial just that.  Try adjusting your dialplan rules so that instead of it matching "1403" it matches "1403XXXXXXX"

Comment: 1403 is a phone number of a operator. It doesn't mean if I call to that number, a land number or a mobile number. I'm from Spain

Comment: Do other numbers work?  If not, I'd suggest turning sip debug on as it could be a codec problem.

Comment: Hello. Other numbers don't work. How do I turn on sip debug? Anyway, I don't think that it could be a codec problem because I can receive call and talk with no problem.

Comment: Are you receiving calls over the same pstn connection?  Which version of asterisk are you running?  When you connect using "asterisk -r" it will give version information.

Comment: Hello. Yes, I receive calls without problems over the same pstn conenection. The version of Asterisk is Asterisk 1.6.0.26-FONCORE-r78. Thanks

Comment: Any idea? I don't know what's happening...

Comment: Have you tried contacting the vendor of your card?  Also try posting the output with "sip set debug on".